# Easiest way to solve this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I was solving this problem from a calculus textbook and I got stuck at this particular problem. I tried to put it into [Integral Calculator](http://www.integral-calculator.com/) after I was unable to solve it, but now I wonder if there is an easier way.

What is the easiest way to solve the following indefinite integral:
$$\int  \frac{x dx}{1 + \cos x}, x \in (-\pi, \pi)$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please improve the question by including key context: *why* would someone want to solve the integral? In other words, what is the motivation for looking at the integral in the first place? There are an infinite number of possible integrals, and even the ones that are of interest could arise in different situations. So the best questions on this site include the background of their problem, not just a statement of an integral to evaluate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $$\cos x=2\cos^2\frac x2-1,$$ then
\begin{align*}
\int\frac x{1+\cos x}dx&=\int\frac x{2\cos^2 \frac x2}dx\\[3pt]
&=\int x\sec^2\frac x2\cdot \frac12dx\\[3pt]
&=\int x\cdot d\left(\tan \frac x2\right)\\[3pt]
&=x\tan \frac x2-\int\tan \frac x2dx\tag{P}\\[3pt]
&=x\tan \frac x2+2\log\left(\cos \frac x2\right)+C
\end{align*}
Where (P) is integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by $\displaystyle\frac{1-\cos x}{1-\cos x}$ gives $\displaystyle\int\frac{x(1-\cos x)}{\sin^2x}dx=\int x\left(\csc^2x -\csc x\cot x\right) dx$.

Now integrate by parts, with $u=x$ and $dv=(\csc^2x-\csc x \cot x) dx$ and  $v=\csc x-\cot x$ to get

$\hspace{.3 in}\displaystyle x(\csc x-\cot x)+\ln|\sin x|-\ln|\csc x-\cot x|+C$

$\hspace{.3 in}\displaystyle=\frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos x}+\ln(1+\cos x)+C$